# Hyperlinks not handled in comments in interaction with MathJax followed by some specific characters

Tags: bug, comments, hyperlinks, mathjax

On at least some¹ MathJax-enabled websites, in a comment² with a MathJax sequence immediately followed by a `/` or `+` (but not a space or a `-`), a subsequent `[text](url)` is mishandled if followed by another MathJax sequence.

For example

```
For $\LaTeX$/MathJax see [this](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1070/555). $n=1$.
```

and variations yield (with Firefox):

[image: Example of the issue]

This is visible [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/448/555), used as a testbed.

<sup>It happened in [this comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/180837), where I ended up using the space workaround.</sup>

---

¹ Likely those using `$` to introduce MathJax sequences, not those using `\$`, see [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1171452).

² This does not happen in [an answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/81555/555).

Comment: I tested this on Code Review (which uses the `\$` delimiter) and there this works just fine.